# How to Find Ending Index of Line in java

Tags: java

i want starting and ending index of below text...

Here Starting is fixed but ending word is not fixed..ending is upto line ends...

Line is :

```
Cardiovascular:ROS:Neurological:
Cardiovascular:ROS:XYZ:
Cardiovascular:ROS:ABC:::
```

i can find starting index but how to find ending index..as it is not fixed.

Comment: so what exactly do you need on these three examples

Comment: this is just a part of paragraph...i have whole document in that there is one line which contain above String(not fixed as discussed above).

Answer (score 2):

If you use a Regex Matcher, it will provide you with a start and end index for each match.

**Sample code**

```
// move this to a constant
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "\\b  # word boundary (start of word) \n" +
        "\\w+ # one or more word characters \n" +
        "\\b  # another word boundary (end of word)", Pattern.COMMENTS);

final String line = "Cardiovascular:ROS:Neurological:";
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("Found word "+matcher.group()+" at start index: "+matcher.start()+ ", end index: "+matcher.end());
}
```

**Output:**

> Found word Cardiovascular at start index: 0, end index: 14
>   Found word ROS at start index: 15, end index: 18
>   Found word Neurological at start index: 19, end index: 31

If you need a column index, use one Matcher per line, but if you need an index from the start of the String, don't split the lines, run the Matcher on the entire String.

Answer (score 0):

if you are storing that line as a `String`, then `yourString.indexOf(yourString.substring(yourString.length-1));`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the index of the last character in a line of type String, then index = line.length() - 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could use string tokenizer to turn your strings into tokens and take the first and loop through the tokens until you get to the last.

**Code**

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class App {

    static String in = "Cardiovascular:ROS:Neurological:";
    static String in2 = "Cardiovascular:ROS:XYZ:";
    static String in3 = "Cardiovascular:ROS:ABC:::";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in2, ":");
        if(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String first = st.nextToken();
            for (int i = 0; i < st.countTokens()-1; i++) {
                st.nextToken();
            }
            String last = st.nextToken();
            System.out.println(first + " " + last);
            System.out.println(in2.indexOf(last));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to get, but if it is the last valid String between `":"` for each line.

```
String source = "Cardiovascular:ROS:Neurological:" + "\n" +
        "Cardiovascular:ROS:XYZ:"                  + "\n" +
        "Cardiovascular:ROS:ABC:::"                + "\n" ;

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader( source ));

while( true ) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if(line == null) {
        break;
    }
    String[] split = line.split( ":" );
    for( int i = split.length; i >= 0; i-- ) {
        String part = split[i-1];
        if(!part.isEmpty()){
            int lineIndex  = line.lastIndexOf( part );
            int lineOffset = source.lastIndexOf( line );
            System.out.println("found: "+part+ " line-index: "+lineIndex+ " text index: "+(lineOffset+lineIndex));
            break;
        }
    }
}
reader.close();
```

out

```
found: Neurological line-index: 19 text index: 19
found: XYZ line-index: 19 text index: 52
found: ABC line-index: 19 text index: 76
```